# Android Camera app receiving Error 100

Tags: android, camera

I am receiving A `Camera Error 100` when following the tutorial given to us by google AND using the emulator. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html. When I use my actual device, it works! Another change I had to make to the tutorial was when the call to `Camera.open()` I had to pass in an integer `Camera.open(0)` and I had to bump up the API to 9. Can anyone tell me why my emulator is giving me Camera Error 100 on the logcat, but the actual device works with no issues? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Camera Error 100 means "Media server died. In this case, the application must release the Camera object and instantiate a new one."
have a look on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

[image: CAMERA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED]
you can see why you are receiving Camera Error 100.

Hope help you..